# Symfony2 get a form with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, render

I have a liste of customers, for each customer I have a button to show the edit form of customer.
I want when I click into this button, a function ajax show the edit form of the specific customer clicked.

I don't know how can do to render a form into the action (controller) executed with AJAX.

Here the way I create the form in my controller:

```
public function editAction($id)
    {
        if ($this->container->get('request')->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $entity = $em->getRepository('ApplicationClientBundle:Client')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Client entity.');
            }

            $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);

            $answer =$this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('ApplicationClientBundle:Client:index.html.twig', array(
                'editForm' => $editForm->createView(),
            ));

            $response = new Response(json_encode(array('editForm'=> $answer)));
            $response->headers->set('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
            return $response;
        }



    }
```

But the response json is empty.

What can I do in the controller and in the index.html.twig to show the form?

**EDIT:**

In `index.html.twig`, I have:

```
{% block body %}
<div class="content-action">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <p><span>Raison Sociale :</span><span id="raison_sociale" onclick="functionClick(this)">raison sociale</span></p>
        <p><span>Adresse :</span><span id="adresse"> Avenue Majida Boulila imm.....</span><p>
        <p><span>M.F. :</span><span id="matriculeFiscale"> 0000000 PES 000</span></p>
        <p><span>C.P. :</span><span id="codePostal"> 3027</span></p>
        <p><span>Ville :</span><span id=""> Sfax<span/></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <p><span>Tél. :</span> 74 400 202</p>
        <p><span>E-mail :</span><span id="email"> info@ggg.com.tn</span></p>
        <p><span>Nom du contact :</span><span id="nomContact"> nom</span></p>
        <p><span>Tél. Mobile :</span><span id="telephone"> 23 447454</span></p>
        <p><input type="hidden" id="id" value="2"/> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!--content-action-->
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
<script>
        function functionClick(element){
        var id = $("#id").val();
            var route = '{{ path('client_edit', { 'id': "PLACEHOLDER" }) }}';
            route = route.replace("PLACEHOLDER", id);
             $.ajax({


                    //On lui indique le type d'envoie des informations

                    type: 'POST',

                    //On lui indique le chemin de la fonction

                    url:  route,



                    //On lui donne la valeur du choix qu'on a fait, et id est la variable qui va contenir notre valeur, nous la retrouvons dans notre controller




                    //Enfin nous lui disons de remplir notre formulaire avec le resultat  

                    success: function(response)

                    {

                        element.innerHTML= {{ the_first_fiels_of_the_form }};
                    }

                }

            );

        }

    </script>
 {% endblock %}
```

I want have `the_first_fiels_of_the_form` in the element clicked.

I do:    `the_first_fiels_of_the_form ={{form_widget(editForm.raisonSociale)}}`
But no result.

Comment: Ok, Lets get a bit into detail: can you provide the template where you do the ajax call (the important bits, not the whole thing) and the template `ApplicationClientBundle:Client:index.html.twig`

Comment: Does rendering the template actually return something? Is `$answer` set?

Comment: the json response is empty : {"editForm":{"headers":{}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem like this:

In the controller, I do:

```
public function editAction($id)
{
    if ($this->container->get('request')->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('ApplicationClientBundle:Client')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Client entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);

         return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('ApplicationClientBundle:Client:cordonner.html.twig', array(
        'editForm' => $editForm->createView()
        ));
}
```

In the template `"index.html.twig"`, I do:

```
{% block body -%}


...
 {% for entity in entities %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ entity.raisonSociale}} </td>
        <td>{{ entity.login }}</td>
        <td>{{ entity.password }}</td>
        <td>{{ entity.soldeSMS }}</td>
        <td>

        <a class="modifier-client handler" data-id="{{ entity.id }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon1">Update</span></a>
        <a href="#historique" class="modifier-client"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon2">Voir Historique</span></a>
        <a href="#ajout" class="modifier-client"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon3">Ajout transaction</span></a>
        <input type="hidden" name="id_client" id="id_client" value=""/>
    </td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}

<div id="cordonner">
    {% include 'ApplicationClientBundle:Client:cordonner.html.twig' %}
</div>

...
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
$('.handler').click(function() {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var route = '{{ path('client_edit', { 'id': "PLACEHOLDER" }) }}';
            route = route.replace("PLACEHOLDER", id);
            $.ajax({


            //On lui indique le type d'envoie des informations

            type: 'POST',

            //On lui indique le chemin de la fonction

            url:  route,  //<==> editAction($id_customer_selected)



            //On lui donne la valeur du choix qu'on a fait, et id est la variable qui va contenir notre valeur, nous la retrouvons dans notre controller




            //Enfin nous lui disons de remplir notre formulaire avec le resultat  

            success: function(response)

            {

                $('#cordonner').html(response);
                $(".client").hide();
                $(".fich-client").show();
                document.location="#cordonner";


            }

        }

    )});
{% endblock %}
```

and in the `"cordonner.html.twig"`, I do:

```
{% if editForm is defined %}
    {{ form(editForm)}}
{% end if%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
```

and later:

```
$response = new JsonResponse();
$response->setData(array('editForm'=> $answer));
return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why return json in the first place if you just have a rendered template in it?

```
public function editAction($id)
    {
        if ($this->container->get('request')->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $entity = $em->getRepository('ApplicationClientBundle:Client')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Client entity.');
            }

            $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);


            return $this->render('ApplicationClientBundle:Client:index.html.twig', array(
                'editForm' => $editForm->createView(),
            ));;
        }



    }
```

This will do the same. It will return a html response which you can easily append in javascript in the view.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The second parameter if $this->render is an array of data you provide the template with.